# An optimization in Markov Chain

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, it.information-theory, markov-chains

We are given two correlated random variables $V$ and $X$ supported over a finite alphabets $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{X}$. Suppose the marginal $P_V$ and conditional distribution $P_{X|V}$ are assumed to be fixed.

What we want is to constructed a random variable $Z$ from $X$ such that $D(P_{XZ} || P_XP_Z)$ becomes maximum while keeping $D(P_{VZ} || P_VP_Z)\leq \epsilon$.

In other words, we want a conditional distribution $P_{Z|X}$ such that the maximum of $$I(X;Z):=\sum_i P(x_i)D(P_{Z|x_i}|| P_Z)$$ 
 is achieved subject to $$I(V;Z)=:\sum_j P(v_j)D(P_{Z|v_j}|| P_Z)\leq \epsilon.$$

Note that $I(X;Z)$ and $I(V;Z)$ are called the mutual information. Hence, this problem looks at the channel (conditional distribution) between $X$ and $Z$ which sends **most** information about $X$ but **not** about $V$ to $Z$.

As a remark, note that if $V$ and $X$ are independent, then $I(X;Z)$ can be as large as $H(X)$ by a noiseless channel.

The most straightforward for this problem is Lagrange multiplier. This method, however, is really hard to work with to get a nice closed-form solution for the upper-bound of the mutual information $I(X;Z)$.

I guess the upper bound is a kind of measure of closeness between $X$ and $V$, something like   Hirschfeld–Gebelein–Rényi maximal correlation.

Any comment is greatly appreciated.